# CSS Hover on Mobile Device

Tags: css, mobile, hover

To state up front, I am a beginning programmer.  I needed to turn off the hover feature on my images for mobile devices, as it was creating issues when someone was scrolling down the page.  I asked a programmer to do it on upwork.com and he successfully did it through CSS for the home page images.

However, I have now added some new images under different sections these new images have it enabled.  Unfortunately, the programmer I used did not want to share how he did it, but rather wanted us to hire him again.

I figured it best to figure out how to do this on my own.

The page is foxandowlkids.com/index_postlaunch.html

You will see that the "The Features" image has hover on a laptop but turned off on mobile.  How can I accomplish this with my "The Versatility" images?  To be honest, not even sure which CSS file I should be looking in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try using your browsers developer tools to inspect what the web page is doing, and which css files/classes are in effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines `3478` and `3460` in `/www/css/style.css` are causing the effect. To disable it you could either wrap those declarations (including selectors) in a `@media` query or you could override them from a different file.

To modify them in place you could use:

```css
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .works-grid.hover-white .work-item:hover .work-img:after{
    background: rgba(250,250,250, .9);
  }
}
/* ... */
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .work-item:hover .work-img:after{
    background: rgba(20,20,20, .85);
  }
}
```

However, I recommend the second option, to place your mods in a different stylesheet, loaded after `style.css`, because mods to style.css will be lost on theme update, (unless you're using a child theme, which doesn't seem to be the case). So here it is, the safer route, to be placed in your own stylesheet:

```css
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .works-grid.hover-white .work-item:hover .work-img:after,
  .work-item:hover .work-img:after {
      background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

There are chances you want to trade the `768px` breakpoint for `992px` if you want to include tablets in affected devices or for `540px` if you only want to limit the change to (most) smart phones.

---

However, please be advised it is always a bad idea to allow unqualified code in production, as the chances of breaking things unknowingly are huge. As a general rule, paying a few bucks for something this small is always worth over the risk of breaking it on a different screen size or different device, which is quite high unless you understand what your code changes, when it applies and how you can test it.

Play on test environments all you want and use it to learn. But if you care about your website and your brand image in front of your clients, don't change things you don't understand in production, be it `CSS`, `javascript` or `php`. It's not a matter of ***if*** you'll break it, but ***when***. Don't take my word for it. Ask any 10 or more developers of your choice, without any work relationship to you and see the answers.

Answer (score 0):

On that particular site the trick seems to be to look out for that class in the `<html>` element. On normal screens, it has the class .no-mobile. For mobile devices, this changes to be .mobile.

Go through the css and look for stuff like this where there's a :hover state:

```
.work-item:hover .work-img > img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Modify it so that there's a html.no-mobile selector in front of everything. This will let you only target screens that are not considered 'mobile.' The modified code might look something like this:

```
html.no-mobile .work-item:hover .work-img > img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Please know that this will only work in your case because there's obviously a script somewhere that is checking for the type of device the user is using and updating the html class, which you can take advantage of.

Using pure CSS, you would need to write media queries and target specific device widths. Rewriting your effects might look something like this, which only targets devices with a screen size of 768px or larger:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .work-item:hover .work-img > img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this help!